# Can white eggs be considered as non-vegetarian?

Tags: food, diet, vegetation

I am basically a [vegetarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian) and I find it very difficult to get an actual biological answer for this question on search engine.

There are couple of links which discuss these argument but can not be acclaimed as a proof as being Egg either a veg or non-veg food item. Below are couple of links which I found depicted this in authors perception:

- [Egg Non-Veg (a proof)](http://veg.tribe.net/thread/6bc5671e-70d6-4aa9-a1af-f46b627aa809)
- [Egg is veg](http://log.amitshah.net/2006/02/eggs-vegetarian-or-non-vegetarian/)
- [Types of vegetarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian)
- [If it is veg why products are marked with red dots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian_mark)

Is there any biological proof to consider **White Eggs** either as vegetarian or non-vegetarian?

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking about **white** eggs, vs., say, brown eggs? Does color make a difference?

Comment: @MattDMo Yeah ! I heard that brown eggs can be fertilized to get a chicken but white can or can not be (which sounds confusing to me).

Comment: That is untrue. The color of the egg is simply a function of the genetics of the chicken - different strains of chickens lay different-colored eggs - google "chicken egg colors" for some interesting pictures and articles

Comment: @MattDMo one of the links the OP posted mentions that the shell changes color when the egg has been fertilized and claims that unfertilized eggs are vegeterian (!).

Comment: @terdon That is headshaking stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course eggs are not vegetarian. Eggs are, well, the *eggs* of chickens (usually). Chickens are animals so their eggs are animal matter as well. Whether or not the egg has been fertilized is completely irrelevant, eggs are chicken just as much as [drumsticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drumstick_%28poultry%29#Cuts_of_poultry) are.

The color of the egg has nothing at all to do with it. All eggs are, by definition, animal cells. Basically, the chicken's egg is the equivalent to the human [ovum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_cell). In both humans and chickens, the female will regularly produce eggs and discard them. In the case of a human woman this is the monthly period. When an egg is not fertilized, it is discarded along with some cells of the wall of the uterus. Similarly, in chickens, the female produces and lays eggs. If an egg has been fertilized, it can grow into a new chicken. If it has not been fertilized, it cannot become a new chicken but is most certainly still an animal cell.

So yes, eggs are most certainly animal, not plant or any other kind of matter. Whether or not you should eat them is up to your own moral guidelines to decide. While they are animal tissue, no animal has been killed to obtain them and no harm comes to the chicken if we harvest them.

Comment: Great answer @terdon, but I'd suggest changing the first sentence. I think the whole premise of OPs question is that "vegetarian" is a loose cultural concept and doesn't necessarily mean "eating no animal matter". As you suggest at the end it might mean "causing no harm", or not eating animals of certain types (the "vegetables and fish" vegetarians).

Comment: @Oreotrephes the OP is free to use the word as he or she desires but asked specifically for a _biological_ answer. From a biological point of view, eggs are categorically animals and not plants or fungi and as far as this biologist is concerned, anything that consists of animal cells is an animal and can therefore not be vegetarian in the strictest sense.

Comment: Point taken, and I suppose OP specifically asks: "vegetarian or non-vegetarian"

Comment: @terdon +1 Thanks for the nice explanation. May be that's why even being a animal product milk doesn't comes under non-veg food items because it does not contains animal cells. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite that depends on your definition of vegetarian. [Vegans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism), for example, do not eat milk or dairy products. Milk is bound to contain at least _some_ animal cells. It is not _made_ of them but it will contain some. In any case, there is very little (basically none) scientific basis to any of these categories, its a personal choice, do whatever feels right to you.

Comment: "While they are animal tissue, no animal has been killed to obtain them and no harm comes to the chicken if we harvest them." - There are still a lot of chickens hurt or killed in the process: Roosters go straight into the chicken nuggets and when hens stop laying enough eggs after 70 weeks of age they will also be "disposed". Also caged eggs and free-range eggs come from chickens in cages or sheds (they will never come outside). Chickenfoods can come from animal parts (even chicken itself). Your best bet on animal wellfare is biological eggs or no eggs at all (like vegans do).

Comment: Most of the egg's matter does not consist of cells. It is just a big bag of proteins.

Comment: I think eggs are OK for most vegetarians, but definitely a nogo  for vegans. Often, it is specifically meat that is avoided by vegetarians, and many allow themselves to consume fish. "Vegetarian" is a loosely defined term and I'm afraid I have to disagree with your claim that eggs are not part of a vegetarian diet.

Comment: @Anixx actually, none of the egg's matter _consists_ of cells. The egg itself is a single, huge cell.

Comment: @ChrisStronks I never made any such claim. The OP asked for a biological answer, not a cultural one. Eggs are animal cells and, therefore,  animals. Whether you should eat them or not is up to your own sense of morality and I wouldn't presume to offer an opinion. That they are an animal cell is not debatable however, that is a simple fact.l

Comment: @terdon no, it has a cell+a lot of protein. Fertilized egg does NOT divide into two halves as a whole, only the cell divides in a tiny piece of the egg.